# Video Streaming not working in some mobile

Tags: android, wowza, wowza-transcoder

We're working on to develop a live video stream application based on android mobile camera. I used RTMP and RTSP ports using WOWZA server.
It is working fine with almost all brand mobiles successfully. When the event is created and started broadcasting of video, data is posting successfully to server. 
But coming to some particular model mobiles like Micromax, Lenovo and etc., the app is not able to post the data from camera. The error message will be like 'Try again..' and broadcast is not successful.

As per my observation, the above said model mobiles are using MT65XX chipset. I tried on various mobiles using the same chipset and failed to broadcast the data.  But other applications like Livestream, Ustream and working fine with these models.

Can someone help me to solve the issue with the above models so that my application runs successfully on all model chipsets.

Here is my application environment:
Developed on android Ice cream sandwich (android 4.0) and it'll supports ICS & above android environments
Library file used while developing application "[B]libstreaming-4.0.jar[/B]"
Thanks in advance. 
Aditya